# не могу подключить контроллер через spl_autoload_register с использованием namespace

Tags: php

Есть контролер indexController c namespace Controller который лежит в папке Controller.
Хочу его подключить с помощью  автозагрузки:

```
<?php
function autoload ($className){

    echo $file=SITE_DIR .'\\'.$className.'.php'; //echo выводит "opt/lampp/htdocs/site\indexController.php"
    if(file_exists($file)){
        include $file;
    }
    die('404 ошибка');
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

но выдает 404 ошибка?
в index.php я создаю

```
$controller = new Controller\indexController();
$controller->index();
```

Наверное проблема в обратном слеше но как исправить не знаю

Comment: Какой ОС пользуетесь?

Comment: У вас мало того что относительный путь, так и `\\` в качестве разделителя (должен быть обычный слэш `/`)

Comment: @etki в Windows это может быть и `\`. Если скрипт используется на разных ОС то нужно использовать DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Comment: @lyhoshva L в LAMPP - это Linux